# uWSGI Segmentation Fault while using Flask-ReCaptcha

Tags: python-3.x, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I've got a problem using a Flask-ReCaptcha feature on my server (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS). On my local machine everything works just fine, but when I run the same project on the server, it fails while validating the ReCaptcha, just after I place a tick.

Logs:

```
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m 2020-01-27 12:03:35,761 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m 2020-01-27 12:03:35,761 INFO success: uwsgi entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m [pid: 17|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.10.0.4 () {50 vars in 888 bytes} [Mon Jan 27 12:03:48 2020] GET / => generated 219 bytes in 13 msecs (HTTP/1.0 302) 3 headers in 140 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m 10.10.0.4 - - [27/Jan/2020:12:03:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 219 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "111.111.111.111"
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m 10.10.0.4 - - [27/Jan/2020:12:03:48 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.0" 200 1441 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "111.111.111.111"
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m [pid: 16|app: 0|req: 1/2] 10.10.0.4 () {48 vars in 873 bytes} [Mon Jan 27 12:03:48 2020] GET /login => generated 1441 bytes in 29 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 2 headers in 81 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m !!! uWSGI process 16 got Segmentation Fault !!!
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m 10.10.0.4 - - [27/Jan/2020:12:03:59 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.0" 502 559 "https://dashboard.antifraud.kektaxi.app/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36" "111.111.111.111"
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m 2020/01/27 12:03:59 [error] 11#11: *5 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.10.0.4, server: , request: "POST /login HTTP/1.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "dashboard.antifraud.kektaxi.app", referrer: "https://dashboard.antifraud.kektaxi.app/login"
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 16) died, killed by signal 11 :( trying respawn ...
[36mantifraud-dashboard_1           | [0m Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 18)
```

I'm using Python 3.7 both on the server and local machine. Installed libraries list:

```
bcrypt==3.1.7
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
dnspython==1.16.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-ReCaptcha==0.4.2
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.19
protobuf==3.6.1
pycparser==2.19
PyYAML==5.3
requests==2.22.0
six==1.13.0
urllib3==1.25.8
Werkzeug==0.16.0
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = antifraud_dashboard
callable = app
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.7

VOLUME /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN echo "uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom_timeout.conf

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## Update:

`UWSGI_LAZY_APPS=1` seems to have no effect, but after setting `PYTHONFAULTHANDLER =1` I've got the following traceback:

```
antifraud-dashboard_1           | Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
antifraud-dashboard_1           |
antifraud-dashboard_1           | Current thread 0x00007f3bb4296780 (most recent call first):
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748 in getaddrinfo
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61 in create_connection
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 157 in _new_conn
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 300 in connect
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994 in _validate_conn
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376 in _make_request
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672 in urlopen
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449 in send
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646 in send
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533 in request
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60 in request
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75 in get
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_recaptcha.py", line 80 in verify
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "./antifraud_dashboard.py", line 94 in login_user
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935 in dispatch_request
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949 in full_dispatch_request
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446 in wsgi_app
antifraud-dashboard_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463 in __call__
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `PYTHONFAULTHANDLER` environment variable to something, e.g. `1`, and you might get a traceback (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-c-extension-crashes/)
2. uWSGI has some bad defaults, bad enough that I personally recommend against using it because of that, but if you must: set `UWSGI_LAZY_APPS` env variable to `1`. By default uWSGI does a fork()-without-exec(), which is a recipe for crashes and mysterious bugs. May not be the issue in this case, but still a thing to set.

Comment: Updated a question with a traceback

Comment: Not sure how env variables for uWSGI interact with the uwsgi config file, so worth trying setting that as a config option there.